# Can I set XMLHttpRequest.timeout to be greater than connection-timeout in browser?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, connection-timeout

I am trying to make a very long call probably more than 5min. But since browser timeout defaults to 90. i.e. in `about:config` section see `network.http.connection-timeout` property in firefox.

Since `XMLHttpRequest` has `timeout` property which can be used to control the timeout of ajax calls (it defaults to 0 i.e. unlimited), so can I set this timeout value to be more than `connection-timeout`?

Would my long call be able to complete?

**Update:**
When I tried these long calls they fails in firefox but succeeds in chromium browser. Any idea why?

Comment: Why would a call take longer than 5 min? Could you not poll until you can get a response?

Comment: @JoeyCiechanowicz There is a scenario which I need at the moment. I know its not right way but still.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the maximum timeout can be set in jquery ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509926/what-is-the-maximum-timeout-can-be-set-in-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @JoeyCiechanowicz That question still doesn't have definite answer yet. But my question is still different in some terms.

Comment: What happens when you set the `timeout` to a huge value? What have you tried?

Comment: I am not getting constant results. Sometimes it gets completed sometimes it doesn't.